# What does this error mean when im trying to compile in c#?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

Here is the code

```
namespace FitnessApp
{
    /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Database db = new Database();
        Exercise exercise = db.getAllMuscleGroups();
        lbMuscleGroup.Items.Add(exercise);
    }
}
```

}

and xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="FitnessApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FitnessApp"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="lbMuscleGroup" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="106" Margin="86,144,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" SelectionChanged="lbMuscleGroup_SelectionChanged"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="lbSelected" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="334,149,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140"/>
</Grid>
```

This is the error:

> Error   CS1061  'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'lbMuscleGroup_SelectionChanged' and no accessible extension method 'lbMuscleGroup_SelectionChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'MainWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    FitnessApp  C:\Users\Remco\OneDrive - Office 365 Fontys\FUN12\Killer-app\FitnessApp\FitnessApp\MainWindow.xaml  10  Active

How do i fix this error? keep getting this error. Very annoying.

Comment: Your lbMuscleGroup_SelectionChanged is not exist in your cs code behind

Comment: It means exactly what it says. In your xaml you have said there is a function called `lbMuscleGroup_SelectionChanged`, but there is no definition for it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

In your XAML code you define "*lblMuscleGroup*" as having an on change event:

```
SelectionChanged="lbMuscleGroup_SelectionChanged"
```

In your MainWindow code, you don't have this defined, so it's saying "Hey! I'm looking for this thing you said you had, but you don't have it! Did you forget something?"

So adding the following should work:

```
private void lbMuscleGroup_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //something happens
}
```

Or you could just remove the "SelectionChanged="lbMuscleGroup_SelectionChanged" part from your XAML.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks alot, it helped.